# Popup displaying image on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, image, popup

I would like to know how to make a popup appear displaying an image after pressing a button. I've seen it on other apps and it's different than an alertView. It appears with a black border and a cross to dismiss.
Anyone?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

A pop-up is just a image with a cross button to dismiss.

Comment: or are u talking about the thing with a black border like you said, but there is no cross button